# Pandas find row with closest profile

Tags: python, pandas

I have a file full of profiles that look like this:

```
 profile_id  colA  colB  colC  colD
 1           1     20    50    63
 2           1     20    65    38
 3           8     5     3     4
 4           98    1     878   4
 ...
```

I have another CSV with results from which I want to find the profile:

```
col    value    score
colA   1        85
colA   1        856
colA   8        200000
colB   1        2356
colC   878      99999
colD   4        2
...
```

I want to extract the `value` for each `colX` with the best score and find which profile_id this is associated to in the previous file.

What I've done is working:

```
profiles = pd.read_csv("profiles.csv", sep="\t", index_col=False)
df = pd.read_csv("results.csv", sep="\t", index_col=False)

found_col = set(df["col"])
good_profile = profiles.copy()
for col in profiles.columns:
    if col == "profile_id":
        continue
    elif col not in found_col:
        print(f"{col} not found")
    else:
        value = int(df.loc[df[df["col"] == col]["score"].idxmax()].value)
        good_profile = good_profile[good_profile[col] == value]
 print(good_profile)
```

This give me the result I want but I am first extracting a subset for the first column, then a subset of this subset for the second one etc...

The cool thing with this is I also get a result when I miss some columns which is great.

I was wondering if there were a way for it to do it better without having to use to create subsets over the previous subset.

Comment: Could you clarify your question? I'm not sure what you're asking.

Comment: Basically I'm looking for a better way to get my profile without having to do subset of subets of subsets [...] of the original dataframe.
 But since my code is working, maybe code review stackexchange is more suited though

Comment: You could also consider each row a vector and then calculate the cosine similarity between each vector and your target vector. This would take into account all the rows at once, and not eliminate too quickly depending on the order.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my attempt:

```
# extract the id with max scores
new_df = df2.loc[df2.groupby('col').score.idxmax(), ['col','value']]

# merge
new_df.merge(df1.melt(id_vars='profile_id', var_name='col'),
             on=['col','value'],
             how='left')
```

Output:

```
    col  value  profile_id
0  colA      8           3
1  colB      1           4
2  colC    878           4
3  colD      4           3
4  colD      4           4
```